# Adding background image to jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Hello I want to add a backround in my jsp. How can i do a image on link to my jsp. And also I want to print out catagories like music, sport etc.  on left side. How can ı do these ?

```
enter code here
<%-- 
Document   : success
Created on : 19.Ara.2016, 12:41:49
Author     : BURAK NURÇİÇEK
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>


<% out.println("welcome");
    out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
%>
<%  
    out.println("<a href='Music.jsp'>Sport</a>");
%>
<%  
    out.println("<a href='Music.jsp'>Stage</a>");
%>
<%  
    out.println("<a href='Music.jsp'>Education</a>");
%>
<%  
    out.println("<a href='Music.jsp'>Family</a>");
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use <img> tag to set the background image

Comment: <img src="https://s30.postimg.org/l5ah3sum9/Bug_n_hangi_2.png" style='width:40%;height:80%' alt='[]' />       
i used that one. But it is not fully background. I want to as a background so text box will on the background not left rigth ..

Comment: With respect, this is not a good question for the StackOverflow format. Why not? A small amount of online research, and using `View Source ...` on pages whose layouts you want to emulate, will give you better answers than we can. Try searching for `html background image`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's best to find answers to this kind of question using online research.